# Web Scraping with VBA: collection of strong elements

Tags: vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname, mshtml

I would like to receive the following data for each player:

- Purchase price (this value does not exist for each player!),
- lowest price,
- maximum price.

With my current coding I get as innertext all 3 values. But these are not separated! How can I evaluate these values individually?

If the purchase price does not exist, the placeholder "not found" should be output. How can I do this without an individual id or classname?

HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div class="historyPrice">
      <div>
        <strong>6,2 Mio</strong>
        <span>Gekauft</span>
      </div>
      <div>
         <strong>0,5 Mio</strong> 
         <span>Tiefstwert</span>
      </div>
      <div>
         <strong>9,4 Mio</strong>
         <span>Höchstwert</span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

It´s the same structure without "purchase Price" (in german "gekauft"). But the first "div" is missing.

```
<div class="historyPrice">
      <div>
         <strong>0,5 Mio</strong> 
         <span>Tiefstwert</span>
      </div>
      <div>
         <strong>9,4 Mio</strong>
         <span>Höchstwert</span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

My coding is as follows:

```
Sub PlayerValues()

Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLPlayerValues As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLPlayerValue As Object

Dim URL1 As String
Dim currentRow As Long
URL1 = ws.Cells(currentRow, 11).Value
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate URL1
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

For currentRow = 7 To lastRow

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))
Set HTMLdoc = ie.Document

Set HTMLPlayerValues = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("historyPrice")

For Each HTMLPlayerValue In HTMLPlayerValues
    Debug.Print HTMLPlayerValue.innerText
    Debug.Print "----------"
Next HTMLPlayerValue

Next currentRow
ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there an actual url we can use? Will the other two, and only the other two, strong be present in the absence of purchase price and in the same order?

Comment: You need to have an account on this site. Therefore I don´t added the URL. Without login credentials the site will not load. Sorry. I have added an example without the purchase price. I adjusted my posting above. I think it´s would be easier if the tag "gekauft" will also be shown when it´s will be empty, but that´s unfortnately not the case.

Comment: Did you try chaining `.getElementsByTagName("strong")` onto `HTMLPlayerValue` inside the loop? Set that in a variable and test its length to determine what to write......

Comment: Yes, the strong tag includes the relevant fields. In case of purchase price is not included the length is 10. If a purchase price is included the length is 12. Relevant are only the last 2 respective the last 3 items.

Comment: So, inside the loop the length of each HTMLPlayerValue.getElementsByTagName("strong") is either 10 or 12? If 10 you want last 2 else last 3? If that is the case, you have the logic needed to extract by index.